# adding dynamic query string to '/' route in remix.run

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

in my index.ts remix component which is the default route of '/',

I have a paginated list with a `pageNum` variable passed as a prop. Which is the current page number.

How can I append a query param to the current path to show something like `/?page=3` to the route in remix.run

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the current route path, you can use `<Link to={".?page=3"}>3</Link>`

Or you can use the `useLocation()` hook re-exported from react-router, and do something like this:

```
const location = useLocation();

// location.pathname is your /
```